# Java/SWT/JFace forcefull reload of GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt, reload

I have an app that is supposed to change its language without having to restart. It already uses Resourcebundles for different languages, but since the Menu-Items and other GUI-stuf  gets generated during the first few seconds of the program start, I can't change their Content any more aterwards.

Any Idea what I could do? Or do I have to keep track of every possible GUI-related item?

Comment: hm... I feel tempted to use something like this http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue014.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy option would be to recreate the the UI from scratch -- without restarting the application.

For example, you could hide the old Shell, then show a new one with the same state but different language.

If that's not accepted either ... I'm speculating here ... maybe you could store a localization key for each widget with Widget.setData( String, Object ), then when switching languages traverse the widget tree with Composite.getChildren() -- starting with the Shell -- and use Widget.getData(String) to get resource keys for each widget. However, a single widget might have multiple localizable strings associated with it.

Comment: I tried that but I can't seperate the starting-porgram (which asks for user-credentials) from the main window. (The program was not written by me, so I'm not really sure which parts fit where)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should keep objects that reference the GUI objects so you can update their text when a user selects a new language.